# UWP XAML NavigationMenu Change styles

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

How can I change the Styles of the `NavigationView` in XAML?

By default, the `Minimal` mode has `AlwaysShowHeader="True"` but I want to set it to `AlwaysShowHeader="False"`.

This is not working:

```
<NavigationView
    x:Name="MyNavigationMenu"
    AlwaysShowHeader="False" >
```

Comment: Have you tried making your own styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Simple solution

You could hide it by making the `HeaderTemplate`'s `DataTemplate` empty, but then you coul also easily not set the header at all

```
<NavigationView
   x:Name="MyNavigationMenu"
   Header="Hello World!"
   AlwaysShowHeader="False">
    <NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate />
    </NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="Inner content" />
</NavigationView>
```

[image: Simple solution]

### Better solution

To make the inner content flow into the header area as well, you have to modify the default template. You can find the following inside:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="HeaderContent" 
       ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
       Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" 
       HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
       IsTabStop="False"
       MinHeight="48"
       VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Notice the `MinHeight="48"` property. This causes the header always take up at least 48 effective pixels. If you don't set any `Header` it will still take up 48 pixels in the `Minimal` mode. To fix this, simply remove this property altogether.

Of course now you have to make sure your content is aware that there might be a hamburger menu button above when in `Minimal` mode and you must add some `Margin` when appropriate.

[image: Better solution, content flows into the header area]

#### Complete updated Style

```
<Style x:Key="CustomNavigationMenuStyle" TargetType="NavigationView">
    <Setter Property="PaneToggleButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource PaneToggleButtonStyle}"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="12,5,0,11" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Header" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="NavigationView">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisplayModeGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Compact"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="RootSplitView.PaneBackground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground}"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Minimal">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="HeaderContent.Margin" Value="48,0,0,0"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="TogglePaneGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="TogglePaneButtonVisible"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="TogglePaneButtonCollapsed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="TogglePaneButton.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PaneContentGridToggleButtonRow.Height" Value="4"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="HeaderGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="HeaderVisible"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="HeaderCollapsed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="HeaderContent.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SettingsGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="SettingsVisible"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SettingsCollapsed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="SettingsNavPaneItem.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AutoSuggestGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="AutoSuggestBoxVisible"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="AutoSuggestBoxCollapsed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="AutoSuggestArea.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PaneStateGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="NotClosedCompact"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="ClosedCompact">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="PaneAutoSuggestBoxPresenter.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PaneAutoSuggestButton.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="TitleBarVisibilityGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="TitleBarVisible"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="TitleBarCollapsed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="PaneButtonGrid.Margin" Value="0,32,0,0"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PaneContentGrid.Margin" Value="0,32,0,0"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,8" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{StaticResource PaneToggleButtonSize}" Canvas.ZIndex="100">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid x:Name="TogglePaneTopPadding"/>
                        <Button x:Name="TogglePaneButton" AutomationProperties.LandmarkType="Navigation" Grid.Row="1" Style="{TemplateBinding PaneToggleButtonStyle}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <SplitView x:Name="RootSplitView" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CompactPaneLength="{TemplateBinding CompactPaneLength}" DisplayMode="Inline" IsTabStop="False" IsPaneOpen="{Binding IsPaneOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OpenPaneLength="{TemplateBinding OpenPaneLength}" PaneBackground="{ThemeResource NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground}">
                        <SplitView.Pane>
                            <Grid x:Name="PaneContentGrid">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition x:Name="PaneContentGridToggleButtonRow" Height="56"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="8"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid x:Name="ContentPaneTopPadding"/>
                                <Grid x:Name="AutoSuggestArea" Height="40" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <ContentControl x:Name="PaneAutoSuggestBoxPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding AutoSuggestBox}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsTabStop="False" Margin="12,0,12,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Button x:Name="PaneAutoSuggestButton" Content="&#xE11A;" MinHeight="40" Style="{TemplateBinding PaneToggleButtonStyle}" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="{TemplateBinding CompactPaneLength}"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <NavigationViewList x:Name="MenuItemsHost" ItemContainerStyleSelector="{TemplateBinding MenuItemContainerStyleSelector}" ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding MenuItemContainerStyle}" ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding MenuItemTemplate}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding MenuItemsSource}" ItemTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding MenuItemTemplateSelector}" Margin="0,0,0,20" Grid.Row="3" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{TemplateBinding SelectedItem}"/>
                                <Border x:Name="FooterContentBorder" Child="{TemplateBinding PaneFooter}" Grid.Row="4"/>
                                <NavigationViewItem x:Name="SettingsNavPaneItem" Grid.Row="5">
                                    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Setting"/>
                                    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                                </NavigationViewItem>
                            </Grid>
                        </SplitView.Pane>
                        <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentControl x:Name="HeaderContent" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsTabStop="False" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </SplitView>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```